# Dealing with identical data in a binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Im in the process of teaching myself data structures and I am currently working on a binary search tree. I was curious how you would sort the tree if you had identical data. For example say that my data consists of `[4,6,2,8,4,5,7,3]`.

1. I set 4 as the root element
2. put 6 to the right of it
3. put 2 to the left of 4
4. put 8 to the right of 6

Then I get to 4 where do I put it since `4=4`? To the left or the right?

Option #1
[image: option 1]

Option #2
[image: option 2]

Are either one of these correct or are they both wrong? If they are both wrong could you show me how they should be sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually binary trees do not allow data duplication. If you make a custom implementation you can store a count of elements. TreeSet in Java is an example - it contains only unique elements.

Actually the cases you listed broke the whole structure of the tree. Search operations will look weird now and couldn't be performed with *O(ln n)*. It will take *O(n)* in worst case so you loose all the benefits of this data structure.

Comment: This is simply a design decision, and yes it can provide an optimum solution in cases where you have a large number of duplicates.  In other cases (no duplicates) this significantly increases run time (extra checks on each node).  It STILL comes down to "best-case" vs "worst-case" is defined by your input data set.

Comment: If you have a large number of duplicates it will take O(n) operations to find all of your elements.

Comment: Agreed: as number of unique elements approaches 1, # operations appoachs O(n)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a sort-tree, then what you have will work fine, either way; in the end you'll do a tree-walk and dump the data.

If this is a search-tree, then I'd just drop the extra (redundant) data once it's been encountered; "it exists".  You did say this is a search-tree, and while not ideal, it's not actually broken - if you search for "4" you'll simply catch the root node (in this case), and never decend below that to see any other "4".  It isn't optimal, having all the extra #'s around.

There will be best-case and worst-case situations regardless of which way you choose; don't worry too much about left/right decisions - generally just doesn't matter.  IF you have a solid grasp of details in a known data-stream you'd be able to make an optimal decision for that specific case.